# How to make Dynamics:// URLs work correctly?

Tags: email, templates, axapta, x++

I was reading http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa834376(AX.50).aspx about creating email templates, and I was wondering if there was any explanation on the use of Dynamics:// URLs.  Search isn't very useful with that keyword.

For this line...what would be a sample of %LinkToBusinessData% that I would pass?

```
<a href="Dynamics://%LinkToBusinessData%">Go to &nbsp; %for%</a>
```

How do I make the system recognize that "Dynamics://" should open Dynamics AX?  I've used that basic template and sent a dummy email to myself and the URLs display warnings and don't do anything.

Comment: I figured it out.  You need a local client installed to make it recognize the Dynamics:// URLs.  I had it installed, but I needed to restart.

The %LinkToBusinessData%, or other %keyword% keywords are really just a key-value mapping.  There are some default ones, but you can make your own easily.

Whatever you put in the email template for a keyword will be replaced by the value in the (string,string) map.  Then you pass the xmlParameters and the map to the SysEmailTable::sendMail() function.


xmlParameters = EventActionEmail::createEmailParameterXml(mappings);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You need a local client installed to make it recognize the Dynamics:// URLs. I had it installed, but I needed to restart.

The %LinkToBusinessData%, or other %keyword% keywords are really just a key-value mapping. There are some default ones, but you can make your own easily.

Whatever you put in the email template for a keyword will be replaced by the value in the (string,string) map. Then you pass the xmlParameters and the map to the SysEmailTable::sendMail() function. xmlParameters = EventActionEmail::createEmailParameterXml(mappings);

Answer (score 0):

Check the [About drilling down from an alert e-mail message](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd309661%28AX.50%29.aspx).

Installation requirements:

> To use the drill-down functionality from an e-mail message, users must
>   work from a local Microsoft Dynamics AX client with a local version of
>   the Microsoft Dynamics AX configuration file. The drill-down
>   functionality does not work if users access Microsoft Dynamics AX by
>   an application server.